# ¿Cómo funciona el método Array.reduce?

Tags: javascript

Buen día, estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde me dijeron que debo usar `reduce`.

He estado tratando de entender el `reduce`, pero sigo sin entender y necesito algo para poder guiarme o una explicación, de cómo funciona el método reduce.

```
function sym(args) {
 
 
}

console.log(sym([3, 3, 3, 2, 5], [2, 1, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6, 6], [1, 2, 3], [5, 3, 9, 8], [1])) ;
```

el resultado debe ser.

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Entiendo la explicación pero no el método.

```
[3, 3, 3, 2, 5] y [2, 1, 5, 7]
```

Debo sacar la diferencia simétrica lo que quiere decir que no este en este ni el siguiente array.

lo que que quedaría `[1,3,7]` y luego este busco la diferencia en este. `[3, 4, 6, 6]` y así sucesivamente.

el resultado es solo un array.

> ESTE ES UN EJERCICIO DE FREECODECAMP. LINK: PARA ENTENDERME MEJOR. https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/coding-interview-prep/algorithms/find-the-symmetric-difference

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio y lee [ask]. 1) dale formato a tu código con el botón que indica `{}`, 2) ¿has visto la [documentación en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?, 3) Las mayúsculas dan la sensación de que ESTÁS GRITANDO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método reduce lo que hace es, dado un array de N elementos, reducirlo a un único valor. Para ello recibe un primer parámetro que es una función que realiza alguna operación recibiendo el valor acumulado hasta el momento y el siguiente elemento del array. Por ejemplo, si queremos encontrar el menor elemento de un array, podemos definir una función *reductora* que se quede con el menor elemento de los dos que estamos comparando:

```
function menor(acumulado, actual) {
  if (acumulado < actual) {
    return acumulado;
  } else {
    return actual;
  }
}
```

Veamos un ejemplo usando esta función:

```js
function menor(acumulado, actual) {
  console.log('Recibo', acumulado, actual);
  if (acumulado < actual) {
    return acumulado;
  } else {
    return actual;
  }
}


const array = [45, 39, 5, 15, 4, 56, 87, 90];

console.log('el menor es', array.reduce(menor));
```

En la primera ejecución se toman los dos primeros elementos, siendo el *acumulado* el elemento en la posición 0.

Pero esto es porque no hemos puesto un valor inicial, que es el segundo parámetro que puede recibir el método reduce:

```js
function menor(acumulado, actual) {
  console.log('Recibo', acumulado, actual);
  if (acumulado < actual) {
    return acumulado;
  } else {
    return actual;
  }
}


const array = [45, 39, 5, 15, 4, 56, 87, 90];
const inicial = 9999;
console.log('el menor es', array.reduce(menor, inicial));
```

En tu caso necesitas tener una función que haga la operación que quieres, recibiendo dos arrays y devolviendo el valor que corresponda a la diferencia entre ambos. Una vez tengas esta función, sólo has de usarla en la función reduce:

```
function sym(args) {
  // importante, args no es un array "de verdad"
  return Array.of(args).reduce(diferenciaSimetrica);
}

function diferenciaSimetrica(array1, array2) {
  ... // lo que quieres hacer con los dos arrays
}
```

Comment: Gracias.. por tomarse el tiempo de explicar, ya pude resolverlo.